# List dimensionality after appending two lists

Tags: python

If I have two 2-dimensional lists, how do I append one to the other, such that the final list is still 2-dimensional?

For example:

```
x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
y = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
x.append(y)
print x
```

Prints out:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```

However, I want it to be:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: You should use `.extend(..)` or `+=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append makes new items within a list. Extend is what you are looking for:

```
x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
y = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
x.extend(y)
print x
```

result:
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]

Answer (score 2):

Simply add them:

```
x = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
y = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]

z = x + y

print z
```

Yields

> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]